# ASP.NET MVC Need to bypass "HTTPS required" message

Tags: asp.net, ssl, model-view-controller, identity, identitymanager

I installed Identity Manager (https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Identity-Manager-using-ASPNET-Identity) following that tutorial on the link shared. I don't have an SSL yet for my localhost project, and need a way to get around this "HTTPS required" message that pops up when I go to run the project. I'm thinking the Startup class below may be where I need to do something, but not sure. I also tried to look for settings in Visual Studios as well as look around in IIS for a way to get around this but with no luck.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var factory = new IdentityManagerServiceFactory();
        factory.IdentityManagerService =
          new Registration<IIdentityManagerService>(Create());

        app.UseIdentityManager(new IdentityManagerOptions { Factory = factory });
    }

    private IIdentityManagerService Create()
    {
        var context =
          new IdentityDbContext(
            @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AspIdentity;Integrated Security=false");

        var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>(context);
        var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);

        var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);

        var managerService =
          new AspNetIdentityManagerService<IdentityUser, string, IdentityRole, string>
            (userManager, roleManager);

        return managerService;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IdentityManagerOptions` contains a [`SecurityConfiguration`](https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager/blob/master/source/Core/Configuration/SecurityConfiguration.cs) property, which itself contains a [`RequireSsl`](https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager/blob/master/source/Core/Configuration/SecurityConfiguration.cs#L25) property that you can set to `false`.

```
var factory = new IdentityManagerServiceFactory();
factory.IdentityManagerService = new Registration<IIdentityManagerService>(Create());

var identityManagerOptions = new IdentityManagerOptions { Factory = factory };
identityManagerOptions.SecurityConfiguration.RequireSsl = false;

app.UseIdentityManager(identityManagerOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well shoot, took a day to look around but found the answer just after I posted this question. I found a changed filed in the applicationhost.config file that added the following line:

```
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44380:localhost" />
```

By changing the port in the URL to that, I was able to get around this issue.